# Flutter stack_trace makes `catch` keyword fail to work

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, error-handling

Very simple example:

```
void main() async {
  try {
    await g();
  } catch (e) {
    print('catch e=$e');
  }
}

Future<void> g() {
  throw Exception('fake error');
}
```

As expected, the output is `catch e=Exception: fake error`.

However, by wrapping `g` with `Chain.capture` as follows:

```
Future<void> g() {
  return Chain.capture(() async {
    throw Exception('fake error');
  });
}
```

**Our catch no longer works!** See below:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: fake error
package:yplusplus/main.dart 60:5              g.<fn>
package:yplusplus/main.dart 59:24             g.<fn>
package:stack_trace/src/chain.dart 94:24      Chain.capture.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1354:13                  _rootRun
dart:async/zone.dart 1258:19                  _CustomZone.run
dart:async/zone.dart 1789:10                  _runZoned
dart:async/zone.dart 1711:10                  runZoned
package:stack_trace/src/chain.dart 92:12      Chain.capture
package:yplusplus/main.dart 59:16             g
package:yplusplus/main.dart 52:11             main
dart:ui/hooks.dart 142:25                     _runMainZoned.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1354:13                  _rootRun
dart:async/zone.dart 1258:19                  _CustomZone.run
dart:async/zone.dart 1789:10                  _runZoned
dart:async/zone.dart 1777:12                  runZonedGuarded
dart:ui/hooks.dart 138:5                      _runMainZoned.<fn>
dart:isola<…>
```

This is very counter-intuitive. I wonder how can I solve this problem? In other words, I want to have the full stack trace (so I use capture), but at the same time, I want `catch` to work!

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why don't you access the stack trace from the catch statement itself.  catch (e, s) {
    print("Caught: $e");
    print("Stack: $s");
  }

Comment: Otherwise, I would suggest that the issue is with how the stack_trace package works, rather than Dart itself.

Comment: @GrahamD thanks for the reply. I want full stacktrace in my (unshown) full code example, and only by using capture() can I achieve it

Comment: Fair enough. I find the available stack in a catch statement adequate. I send it back to me from the live app using Catcher package. Works for me.